# Why aren't simulators showing in the Xcode 6.3.1 scheme selector?

Tags: xcode, xcode6.3.1

I cannot seem to build for a simulator in Xcode 6.3.1

The scheme selector only lists `iOS Device` or my plugged in device as seen below:
[image]

`xcodebuild -showsdks` lists it:

```
OS X SDKs:
    OS X 10.9                       -sdk macosx10.9
    OS X 10.10                      -sdk macosx10.10

iOS SDKs:
    iOS 8.3                         -sdk iphoneos8.3

iOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - iOS 8.3             -sdk iphonesimulator8.3
```

It appears to be in the correct location in the app bundle.

I also can't build for i386 and x86_64 using xcodebuild

The output from `xcrun simctl list` is as follows:

```
== Device Types ==
iPhone 4s (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-4s)
iPhone 5 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5)
iPhone 5s (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5s)
iPhone 6 Plus (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6-Plus)
iPhone 6 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6)
iPad 2 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-2)
iPad Retina (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Retina)
iPad Air (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air)
Resizable iPhone (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Resizable-iPhone)
Resizable iPad (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Resizable-iPad)
== Runtimes ==
iOS 8.3 (8.3 - 12F69) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-8-3)
== Devices ==
-- iOS 8.3 --
-- Unavailable: com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-7-0 --
    iPhone 4s (12AE8BFB-0540-4BC0-AB56-459304D05E2A) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPhone 5 (1DA1B3F7-48D5-484E-95F9-CF913DF85B63) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPhone 5s (A1B771C1-834F-4E05-A04F-7E9A3505D46E) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPad 2 (B4E0D353-F942-459E-995C-49183245ECAA) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPad Retina (6D7E2406-9C7A-40DC-B217-D0B0FE3CEAEE) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPad Air (B03E0F6B-3110-40CD-98F8-190726489B56) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
-- Unavailable: com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-7-1 --
    iPhone 4s (0DB72F1A-A5D0-4556-A49E-B96853B439F2) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPhone 5 (22BFA786-5AE0-4ABA-9062-DE358CFB0D6C) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPhone 5s (2F59F49A-AAF8-40C3-BB60-30C729A979F3) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPad 2 (DCAB9F55-9D6B-473E-9433-D2D48203B4DB) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPad Retina (8F74FE32-DE70-4C4B-9D81-21856C9866DA) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPad Air (650CF55A-2BD7-425A-8939-CADEADB7068A) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
-- Unavailable: com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-8-0 --
    iPhone 4s (73837B7E-8E11-4616-AE13-23F60728FBF3) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPhone 5 (2E3268E4-2E35-44BC-AF3D-F32306D44F13) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPhone 5s (C8ECDF4C-DE68-4A73-9ECA-546E85A3DA80) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPhone 6 Plus (BB59A82C-BC47-4B51-A3B8-F0123394292A) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPhone 6 (8E37DC02-393F-4695-980C-8679A5D56E46) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPad 2 (7503B827-8037-4465-AE57-02AFB54CE204) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPad Retina (6629BF4B-6CBA-43A3-8EA2-93272933D086) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPad Air (61747A6D-BDDC-4906-87DA-CB8FD0678A93) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    Resizable iPhone (CFD3BE4E-1205-4EF6-BF4B-F1CFE5490040) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    Resizable iPad (89A63BCF-A654-44BE-8362-5544F5FA1CAF) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
-- Unavailable: com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-8-1 --
    iPhone 4s (FE578030-E512-4643-9F28-FCDCCD74279F) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPhone 5 (9C328DC5-2E4F-47AB-ABBA-1C881DE48795) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPhone 5s (8D91EB18-594B-4288-BBF4-BF2655308706) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPhone 6 Plus (70F1B2D6-966D-49F0-B6CE-BCF995F425CB) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPhone 6 (53510FD4-EEE0-487E-B20E-F9F8AC65BA57) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPad 2 (3B316D24-6497-45C1-BE0D-690FA831D6A3) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPad Retina (55ED45DA-3ACB-479C-9FF9-F0905B47A497) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPad Air (52AE24F1-92AE-4198-A196-32A4691903D8) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    Resizable iPhone (1E16E2F4-BC24-4F3D-AB1F-C07A6FA52E6F) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    Resizable iPad (95254D91-345C-446E-8CC7-72382C0AB8AD) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
-- Unavailable: com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-8-2 --
    iPhone 4s (4370C11F-7486-4E16-AD62-04BC6ECF23CC) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPhone 5 (1635F9A2-5CD6-4669-B69B-493EDA2736BF) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPhone 5s (AD9B417C-BB60-4A94-A080-4E9A00577762) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPhone 6 Plus (A1575F64-44E1-4999-985E-88B890354A36) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPhone 6 (44F34FBC-924E-4226-AF8B-C9C76C618457) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPad 2 (180A9123-2F6C-423D-A124-CAAEEC8661D5) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPad Retina (0BBD9657-498C-4823-BA0B-4A5EA7305224) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPad Air (57E7ED1B-89BB-4C0E-A167-7D6FDD97E838) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    Resizable iPhone (C56D2AC5-9F7A-4C8B-BCED-997A32D7342B) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    Resizable iPad (27E051F5-F718-4BDC-99AA-F8C66B66505E) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
```

The applicable portion of the core simulator log is:

```
May  5 14:31:07 Fangorn-Farm-3.local CoreSimulatorService[6031] <Notice>: com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService 117.15~1 starting.
May  5 14:31:08 Fangorn-Farm-3.local CoreSimulatorService[6031] <Error>: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/montegoulding/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/14E7FDD6-751B-4A81-9CAF-B7F8359C553F/device.plist
May  5 14:31:08 Fangorn-Farm-3.local CoreSimulatorService[6031] <Error>: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/montegoulding/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/57028519-A154-4768-87D7-589111236C12/device.plist
May  5 14:31:08 Fangorn-Farm-3.local CoreSimulatorService[6031] <Error>: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/montegoulding/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/726D5E5A-A5C2-4EEA-B18E-C5174AE7EFD4/device.plist
May  5 14:31:08 Fangorn-Farm-3.local CoreSimulatorService[6031] <Error>: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/montegoulding/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/79272BA7-45B9-47C4-A74E-91A9A1C02141/device.plist
May  5 14:31:08 Fangorn-Farm-3.local CoreSimulatorService[6031] <Error>: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/montegoulding/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A4526FAE-721D-488F-B9F6-D0D6A31EE579/device.plist
May  5 14:31:08 Fangorn-Farm-3.local CoreSimulatorService[6031] <Error>: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/montegoulding/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ACE62A2C-E3E0-408F-A198-983D244107E7/device.plist
May  5 14:31:08 Fangorn-Farm-3.local CoreSimulatorService[6031] <Error>: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/montegoulding/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DB987632-15E5-4CB4-B20C-1FF8FF4606C6/device.plist
May  5 14:31:08 Fangorn-Farm-3.local CoreSimulatorService[6031] <Error>: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/montegoulding/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E1F83FA1-F630-4CDB-9E2D-8792797BEA5E/device.plist
May  5 14:31:08 Fangorn-Farm-3.local CoreSimulatorService[6031] <Error>: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/montegoulding/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E45166AD-7ED3-4001-B01C-3B8F8497ECEA/device.plist
May  5 14:31:08 Fangorn-Farm-3.local CoreSimulatorService[6031] <Error>: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/montegoulding/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FE7A9682-FF80-4F7E-9817-A1B2CFDA0328/device.plist
May  5 14:31:08 Fangorn-Farm-3.local com.apple.dt.Xcode[754] <Warning>: CoreSimulatorService connection interrupted.  Resubscribing to notifications.
```

The content of ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/.default_created.plist is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-7-0</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-2</key>
        <string>B4E0D353-F942-459E-995C-49183245ECAA</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air</key>
        <string>B03E0F6B-3110-40CD-98F8-190726489B56</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Retina</key>
        <string>6D7E2406-9C7A-40DC-B217-D0B0FE3CEAEE</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-4s</key>
        <string>12AE8BFB-0540-4BC0-AB56-459304D05E2A</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5</key>
        <string>1DA1B3F7-48D5-484E-95F9-CF913DF85B63</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5s</key>
        <string>A1B771C1-834F-4E05-A04F-7E9A3505D46E</string>
    </dict>
    <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-7-1</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-2</key>
        <string>DCAB9F55-9D6B-473E-9433-D2D48203B4DB</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air</key>
        <string>650CF55A-2BD7-425A-8939-CADEADB7068A</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Retina</key>
        <string>8F74FE32-DE70-4C4B-9D81-21856C9866DA</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-4s</key>
        <string>0DB72F1A-A5D0-4556-A49E-B96853B439F2</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5</key>
        <string>22BFA786-5AE0-4ABA-9062-DE358CFB0D6C</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5s</key>
        <string>2F59F49A-AAF8-40C3-BB60-30C729A979F3</string>
    </dict>
    <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-8-0</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Resizable-iPad</key>
        <string>89A63BCF-A654-44BE-8362-5544F5FA1CAF</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Resizable-iPhone</key>
        <string>CFD3BE4E-1205-4EF6-BF4B-F1CFE5490040</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-2</key>
        <string>7503B827-8037-4465-AE57-02AFB54CE204</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air</key>
        <string>61747A6D-BDDC-4906-87DA-CB8FD0678A93</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Retina</key>
        <string>6629BF4B-6CBA-43A3-8EA2-93272933D086</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-4s</key>
        <string>73837B7E-8E11-4616-AE13-23F60728FBF3</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5</key>
        <string>2E3268E4-2E35-44BC-AF3D-F32306D44F13</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5s</key>
        <string>C8ECDF4C-DE68-4A73-9ECA-546E85A3DA80</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6</key>
        <string>8E37DC02-393F-4695-980C-8679A5D56E46</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6-Plus</key>
        <string>BB59A82C-BC47-4B51-A3B8-F0123394292A</string>
    </dict>
    <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-8-1</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Resizable-iPad</key>
        <string>95254D91-345C-446E-8CC7-72382C0AB8AD</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Resizable-iPhone</key>
        <string>1E16E2F4-BC24-4F3D-AB1F-C07A6FA52E6F</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-2</key>
        <string>3B316D24-6497-45C1-BE0D-690FA831D6A3</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air</key>
        <string>52AE24F1-92AE-4198-A196-32A4691903D8</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Retina</key>
        <string>55ED45DA-3ACB-479C-9FF9-F0905B47A497</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-4s</key>
        <string>FE578030-E512-4643-9F28-FCDCCD74279F</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5</key>
        <string>9C328DC5-2E4F-47AB-ABBA-1C881DE48795</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5s</key>
        <string>8D91EB18-594B-4288-BBF4-BF2655308706</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6</key>
        <string>53510FD4-EEE0-487E-B20E-F9F8AC65BA57</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6-Plus</key>
        <string>70F1B2D6-966D-49F0-B6CE-BCF995F425CB</string>
    </dict>
    <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-8-2</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Resizable-iPad</key>
        <string>27E051F5-F718-4BDC-99AA-F8C66B66505E</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Resizable-iPhone</key>
        <string>C56D2AC5-9F7A-4C8B-BCED-997A32D7342B</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-2</key>
        <string>180A9123-2F6C-423D-A124-CAAEEC8661D5</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air</key>
        <string>57E7ED1B-89BB-4C0E-A167-7D6FDD97E838</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Retina</key>
        <string>0BBD9657-498C-4823-BA0B-4A5EA7305224</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-4s</key>
        <string>4370C11F-7486-4E16-AD62-04BC6ECF23CC</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5</key>
        <string>1635F9A2-5CD6-4669-B69B-493EDA2736BF</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5s</key>
        <string>AD9B417C-BB60-4A94-A080-4E9A00577762</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6</key>
        <string>44F34FBC-924E-4226-AF8B-C9C76C618457</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6-Plus</key>
        <string>A1575F64-44E1-4999-985E-88B890354A36</string>
    </dict>
    <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-8-3</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Resizable-iPad</key>
        <string>726D5E5A-A5C2-4EEA-B18E-C5174AE7EFD4</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Resizable-iPhone</key>
        <string>14E7FDD6-751B-4A81-9CAF-B7F8359C553F</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-2</key>
        <string>79272BA7-45B9-47C4-A74E-91A9A1C02141</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air</key>
        <string>FE7A9682-FF80-4F7E-9817-A1B2CFDA0328</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Retina</key>
        <string>E45166AD-7ED3-4001-B01C-3B8F8497ECEA</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-4s</key>
        <string>DB987632-15E5-4CB4-B20C-1FF8FF4606C6</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5</key>
        <string>E1F83FA1-F630-4CDB-9E2D-8792797BEA5E</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5s</key>
        <string>57028519-A154-4768-87D7-589111236C12</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6</key>
        <string>ACE62A2C-E3E0-408F-A198-983D244107E7</string>
        <key>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6-Plus</key>
        <string>A4526FAE-721D-488F-B9F6-D0D6A31EE579</string>
    </dict>
    <key>version</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This can happen if you renamed or moved Xcode.app.  Try renaming it back to what it was before or rebooting.  If that doesn't address the issue, your should look at 'xcrun simctl list' and ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices to see if you have any devices.

Also check out ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator for any error logs.

From the added logging and information provided, the issue is that you had iOS 8.3 devices created for you at some point (that is why the UUIDs appear in the . default_created.plist file), but their device.plist files got deleted, so the system is (correctly) no longer listing them.

I'm not sure how the device.plist files got deleted from your system, but you can go back to a vanilla state with:

```
sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
rm -rf ~/Library/*/CoreSimulator
```

Comment: I did rename it but I renamed it back even though I have lots of older versions of Xcode with different names and they don't have issues. I have rebooted multiple times since I noticed and no change. 'xcrun simctl list' shows the devices. ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices shows no 8.3 devices although there are a number of directories without a device.plist. ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator shows unable to load device.plist...

Comment: You'll need to be quite a bit more specific than that.  Please provide the full data in your question.

Comment: I've added the data above... not sure what you might need from ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What happens when you run 'xcrun --noxpc simctl list'?  What is the contents of ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/.default_created.plist ?

Comment: 'xcrun --noxpc simctl list' chokes on the option but 'xcrun simctl --noxpc  list' gives me the same as above.

Comment: Answer updated with instructions for restoring to a clean state.  I'm curious how those device.plist got removed from your system.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks and yes I'd like to know how come those device.plist files weren't created or were deleted... I suspect they weren't created because I never saw the simulators in this version of Xcode at all.

Comment: I've been stuck at the office for hours trying to get my recent XCode 7 install to stop being a brick. That vanilla state command is a lifesaver, thanks so much!

Comment: @ThomasVerbeek Please file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com for whatever is causing your install to not be working well.

Comment: Command to restore to clean state also helped resolving the error "Invalid runtime: com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-8.4", happening while trying to add a new simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Try This...
1.Run the simulator from application(Or from spotlight)
2.Hardware ----> Device---> Manage Device.
3.A popup will open, in that screen bottom left corner you will find "+" use + for adding new simulators for different ios versions

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I downloaded simulators of version iOS 8.2 and in project iOS deployment target was higher than downloaded version so it was not showing, once you will change it lower than downloaded version it will start to show. Please, let me know if you are facing any issue.