# Xcodebuild showSDKs shows different available iOS sims than Xcode 6.3 GUI

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcodebuild

OSX 10.10.1
Xcode 6.3 or 6.3.1
xcodebuild version "Xcode 6.3.1"

This happened on one machine and I thought it was a fluke.  Has now happened on two machines.  I have followed the advice in 
[Why aren't simulators showing in the Xcode 6.3.1 scheme selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980231/why-arent-simulators-showing-in-the-xcode-6-3-1-scheme-selector)

to no avail.  Here is what I see on the command line:

```
xcodebuild -showsdks
iOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - iOS 8.3             -sdk iphonesimulator8.3
```

in "xcode GUI -> prefs -> Downloads"

```
iOS 8.2 Sim (checkmark)
iOS 8.1 Sim (checkmark)
iOS 7.1 Sim (checkmark)
```

in the ios sim application (opened from Xcode -> Open dev tool -> ios sim)

in the "hardware -> device" dropdown menu i see

```
iOS 7.1 > (lots of choices)
iOS 8.1 > (lots of choices)
iOS 8.2 > (lots of choices)
iOS 8.3 > (lots of choices)
```

So the Xcode GUI generally agrees with itself, but I need to build for and kick off all of these iOS sims programmatically from the command line, but xcodebuild doesn't see all of the available simulators.

Comment: Actually the way to know what simulators you've really got is `xcrun simctl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignore what `xcodebuild -showsdks` tells you. You are confusing SDKs with destinations. A simulator is a destination.

- The way to know what simulators you've got is with `xcrun simctl list`.
- The way to tell `xcodebuild` what destination to build for is with the `-destination` option. You can construct and specify any simulator with which your project's deployment setting is compatible.